# Write data to file in a txt from a listener

Tags: java

I have created a window to receive data entered by a user. But I can't get that data to be saved in a txt file.
The txt file has a list of users with the following data (name, surname, email, etc.) and the intention is to add new users to that file. The method used must be through listeners.

The structure of my project is as follows:

1. Class: main
2. Interface: window and window to create user (data is collected here)
3. Listeners:
   button view users
   create users button
   delete users button
   exit button
4. Classes: user, and two of type enum

**The window interface to create the user:**

```
public class buttonCreateUsersActionListener implements ActionListener {
private Window window;


public buttonCreateUsersActionListener () {
    this.window = window;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

**window to create user (data is collected here)**

```
public class CreateUserWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private JLabel labelSubtitle, labelName, labelLastname, labelEmail, labelSex, labelStateCivil, lblFormatDate;
private static JTextField txtName;
private static JTextField txtLastname;
private static JTextField txtEmail;
private JTextField txtDate;
private JButton btnSave, btnCancel;
private Choice chStateCivil;
private final ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup ();

publicWindowCreateUser () {
    String userList = "";
    components ();

    setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize (400,450); // Window Size Width and Length
    setLocationRelativeTo (null); // Center the window on the monitor
    getContentPane (). setLayout (null);
    setResizable (false); // prevents the window size from being modified
    setVisible (true); // make the window visible
    setTitle ("Create and add a user"); // Give the window a title

}

public void components () {

    labelSubtitulo = new JLabel ();
    labelSubtitulo.setFont (new Font ("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    labelSubtitulo.setBounds (92, 20, 260, 20);
    labelSubtitulo.setText ("Fill all the boxes");
    getContentPane (). add (labelSubtitulo);

    / * --------- Fields --------- * /

    labelName = new JLabel (); // label
    labelName.setBounds (20, 50, 150,20);
    labelName.setText ("Name");
    getContentPane (). add (labelName);

    txtName = new JTextField (); // box to fill
    txtName.setBounds (165, 50, 215, 20);
    getContentPane (). add (txtName);

    labelLastname = new JLabel ();
    labelLastname.setBounds (20, 80, 150, 20);
    labelLastname.setText ("Lastname");
    getContentPane (). add (labelLastname);

    txtLastname = new JTextField ();
    txtLastname.setBounds (165, 80, 215, 20);
    getContentPane (). add (txtLastname);

    labelEmail = new JLabel ();
    labelEmail.setBounds (20, 110, 110, 20);
    labelEmail.setText ("Email");
    getContentPane (). add (labelEmail);

    txtEmail = new JTextField ();
    txtEmail.setBounds (165, 110, 215, 20);
    getContentPane (). add (txtEmail);

    labelSexo = new JLabel ();
    labelSex.setBounds (20, 140, 50, 20);
    labelSex.setText ("Sex");
    getContentPane (). add (labelSex);

    JRadioButton rdbtnMan = new JRadioButton ("Man");
    buttonGroup.add (rdbtnMan);
    rdbtnMan.setBounds (165, 139, 80, 25);
    getContentPane (). add (rdbtnMan);

    JRadioButton rdbtnMujer = new JRadioButton ("Female");
    buttonGroup.add (rdbtnFemale);
    rdbtnMujer.setBounds (249, 140, 69, 25);
    getContentPane (). add (rdbtnFemale);

    labelEstadoCivil = new JLabel ();
    labelEstadoCivil.setBounds (20, 170, 80, 20);
    labelEstadoCivil.setText ("Civil Status");
    getContentPane (). add (labelStateCivil);

    chEstadoCivil = new Choice ();
    chEstadoCivil.setBounds (165, 168, 110, 20);
    chEstadoCivil.add ("Single");
    chEstadoCivil.add ("Married");
    chEstadoCivil.add ("Divorced");
    chEstadoCivil.add ("Widower");
    getContentPane (). add (chStateCivil);

    JLabel birthdate = new JLabel ("Date of birth");
    birthdate.setBounds (20, 203, 128, 16);
    getContentPane (). add (birthdate);

    txtDate = new JTextField ();
    txtDate.setBounds (165, 203, 110, 22);
    getContentPane (). add (txtDate);
    txtDate.setColumns (10);

    lblFormatDate = new JLabel ("[format DD / MM / YYYY]");
    lblFormatDate.setFont (new Font ("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    lblFormatDate.setBounds (20, 219, 138, 16);
    getContentPane (). add (lblFormatDate);

    /*---------- Buttons ----------*/

    btnSave = new JButton ();
    btnSave.setBounds (100, 350, 100, 20);
    btnSave.setText ("Save");
    btnSave.addActionListener (this);
    getContentPane (). add (btnSave);

    btnCancel = new JButton ();
    btnCancelar.setBounds (220, 350, 100, 20);
    btnCancelar.setText ("Cancel");
    btnCancelar.addActionListener (this);
    getContentPane (). add (btnCancelar);

}
@Override
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource (). equals (btnSave)) {// We launch a routine to write the data
        this.dispose ();
        User user = null;
        Window.listUsers.add (student);
    }
}
public String getName () {
    return txtName.getText ();
}
public static String getLastname () {
    return txtLastname.getText ();
}
public static String getEmail () {
    return txtEmail.getText ();
}
public String getSex () {
    return labelSexo.getText ();
}
public String getStateCivil () {
    return labelCivilState.getText ();
}
public String getBirthDate () {
    return lblFormatDate.getText ();
}
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run this program?

Comment: It does nothing, it seems to save a new user. But seeing the content of the txt, there is nothing new.

Comment: I don't follow, you have a gui that displays some text, and you want to save it to a file? You have to be somewhat specific. How are you 'seeing the content of the txt'?

Comment: I have a graphical interface that when pressing the button add a new student, a new window opens to fill in the data, then those data must be stored in a txt file.

Comment: I have modified the code to enter new students.

Comment: Can I attach the code with the classes Window, CreateStudentWindow and the buttonCreateStudent?

Comment: So the only part you're having trouble with is saving a String to a text file?

Comment: Well in principle yes, when I press the button to see students I can see the complete list that is in the txt. It is displayed in a text box at the bottom of the window. However, when pressing create new student, the window to put the data opens, but when saving, they are not added to the txt.
I am fairly new to the world of Java, and everything seems to not instantiate the methods correctly.

Comment: "I can see the complete list that is in the txt." what is 'the text'? "they are not added to the txt." again, is this the same 'txt' as before? None of your code has you writing to any files. You have an action listener with code that says. "// TODO Auto-generated method stub" is there where you want to write to the text file?

Comment: At the bottom of the Window class is an output text box.
When I click on the button see students, the list is shown in that box. The file is a txt that I have stored on my pc.

Comment: Can I send you the complete code, so you can see it?

Comment: The goal, when using stackoverflow, is to make a complete example, that demonstrates your issue,and somebody will help you figure out the problem.

Comment: Ok, so can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: But how can I add the code of the class CreateStudent to see the problem?

Comment: I mean the listener createStudent

Comment: Can you a) Get the String you want in the file? b) Get the file? and c) Write the string to the file. One step at a time. Also, you should be able to make a minimal example that demonstrates your problem, with just a JFrame, JTextArea and JButton.

Comment: I need the "c" to write the string to the file.

Answer (score 0):

This will write a file for you, provided you can get the string you want to write to the file, and you can get the path/name of the file.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String content = getContent(); //You said you know how to do this.
    try( BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter( 
            Paths.get( filename ), 
            StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
            StandardOpenOption.APPEND );){
            writer.write(content);
    } catch (IOException e){
        //You might want to do something useful here.
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the main window we have several jlabel, to see the students, to create, to delete and finally to exit.
When clicking on the create student button, a new window opens to fill in the user data. In this window there is a button to save the data, that is, it must write to the txt.
What method should I use to make that button write in the txt?

Comment: Add this action listener to that button. Then when that button is pressed, the new string will get appended to the file.

Comment: I'm going to test to see if it works. Thank you very much for your input.

Comment: So, in the create student window, should I only include the labels and the fields?

Comment: Is there any possibility of putting all the code in the forum to better see where the error is?

Comment: You should put enough code to reproduce the problem you're having. It's best if you can reduce it down in size a bit. Like use less fields for your class.

Comment: Clicking on create a new student in the window shows the following error:

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at aa2.interfaz.Ventana.activarListadoEstudiantes(Ventana.java:153)
 at aa2.escuchadores.botonCrearEstudianteActionListener.actionPerformed(botonCrearEstudianteActionListener.java:23)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)

Comment: And couldn't I send you the code so that you could visualize the failure?

Comment: If you think it is necessary, add it to your question.

Comment: And couldn't I send you the code so that you could visualize the failure?